# RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> confusion

Tags: java, android-studio

I have been learning how to use RecyclerView in android studio. I came across a class extending "RecyclerView.Adapter < RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder >". What is RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder and why is it inside the brackets?

Answer (score 2):

View holder objects:

> They are instances of a class you define by
>   extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Each view holder is in charge of
>   displaying a single item with a view. For example, if your list shows
>   music collection, each view holder might represent a single album.

Adapters:

> The view holder objects are managed by an adapter, which you create by
>   extending RecyclerView.Adapter.

When you extend the RecyclerView.Adapter, you have to specify what kind of view holder you want the adapter use. You do this inside < >. Read up on Generics to better understand this syntax.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

android uses the single view multiple times if list goes byond the screen .
viewHolder is the reference to that view .
when you scroll the list the system will use the previously ganerated views [referenced by the viewHolder with different values init].

[watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLNoMEmcwVM)